# Adding an existing project to a separate existing solution and include in Visual SVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is flawed or whether I'm missing a vital step in Visual SVN somewhere but I'm getting bogged down with this and would appreciate some help!

Say I have two existing solutions in my subversion repository: Sol1 & Sol2.

Both Sol1 & Sol2 currently contain a webProject, a dataProject and a servicesProject.  These projects are unique to each solution and contain entirely separate code.

Now let's say that Sol2 also has a modelsProject which contains model classes for interaction with a 3rd party database we use.  I am now modifying Sol1 and it also requires access to that 3rd party database.

Fairly obviously (to me at least!) I don't want to create a completely separate copy/version of the modelsProject to use in Sol1, I simply want to use/reference the existing modelsProject as exists in Sol2 because it will be exactly the same code in either solution.  However when I try and "add existing project" to Sol1 in Visual Studio, it (quite correctly, of course) tells me that it won't be adding the modelsProject to the Visual svn for Sol1 as it is "outside the working copy root".

Am I missing a fundamental logic problem here? In this kind of scenario where the modelsProject exists in its own right and just happens to be contained within "Sol2" at the moment an incorrect solution and I should instead have "modelsProject" as a standalone visual svn solution which creates a dll and then reference that dll from both Sol1 & Sol2?

Thinking about it I can see that svn would have an issue tracking changes if they were being made from either Sol1 OR Sol2 on the "same" set of code (in modelsProject) so maybe the standalone "modelsProject" as a dll referenced in Sol1 & Sol2 is the logically correct way forward...?

Comment: You should place all files in working copy, or use the `externals`. Files outside of working copy is not under version control. Can you place both of your projects and common code in one repo? SVN repo is hierarhical, you can checkout it separately by subfolder you need.

Comment: Sorry, got side tracked on another problem for a while.  To clarify: I want a situation whereby the common project (be it data access or models - whatever) is NOT editable from the organisational projects that use it.  I want a "closed box" type scenario whereby the independent projects reference the dll for the common project and do something like "commonproject.getCustomerList(param1, param2)" and it spits out the results.  If I need to change how the common project returns data, I open up a separate VS project and edit it then recompile it.

Comment: Read the svn book - `Is Subversion the Right Tool?`http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.intro.whatis.html#svn.intro.righttool. I think you need separated project and put some sync and deploy scripts on it to control for their dependencies.